# Is the ordering of integrals important in a 2D integral?

Tags: definite-integrals

Let's consider $\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x,y)dxdy$ : do we know that $x$ will vary from $a$ to $b$ and $y$ from $c$ to $d$, or said similarly, is the *ordering* crucial in the definition ? Same question for the ordering of dx and dy ?

I'm not asking about Fubini theorem :
I ask explictely if
$\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x,y)dxdy$=$\int_c^d\int_a^b f(x,y)dxdy$
that is : could $x$ be either from $a$ to $b$ or from $c$ to $d$, without changing the result ?

Comment: You can search the Fubini's theorem.

Comment: @Emilio Novati : I'm asking about the *interpretation* of $a$ and $b$ : are there necessary meaning the *first* variable.

Comment: Have you tried any concrete examples, e.g. $$\int_0^1\int_0^2xy^2dxdy\mbox{ versus }\int_0^2\int_0^1xy^2dxdy?$$

Comment: first gives 4/3. Second gives 2/3 : so where is the *rule* that says that the first integral is meaning x ? How could we know ?

Comment: This is the main reason why I prefer the 'forward-operating' notation for definite integrals as $\int_{a}^{b}dx\,f{\left(x\right)}$, and then double integrals $\int_{a}^{b}dx\int_{c}^{d}dy\,f{\left(x,y\right)}$. With this notation there is never any confusion or doubt over which $\int$ goes with which differential!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually $\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x,y)dxdy$ is interpreted as

$$\int_a^b\left(\int_c^d f(x,y)dx\right)dy$$  and this is, in general, different from
$$\int_c^d\left(\int_a^b f(x,y)dx\right)dy$$
as you can see using a simple function as $f(x,y)=x$